# How to pass an r-value std::vector to a function?

Tags: c++

What I would like to do is to call a function that contains an `std::vector` parameter by directly putting an array in the call. I don't want to make a vector and then pass it into the function, but I want to put the braces right in the function. Here is the general idea:

```
void doSomething(std::vector<int> arr)
{
    std::cout << arr[0] << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    doSomething({ 1, 2, 3 });
}
```

This gives me an error. I have also tried using a lambda expression, which I am not quite familiar with, but here it is:

```
doSomething([]()->std::vector<int>{ return{ 1, 2, 3 }; });
```

This does not work. And here is specifically what I don't want:

```
std::vector<int> a {1, 2, 3};
doSomething(a);
```

So how should I approach this? I really hope that what I have written isn't completely stupid.

Comment: The first code block compiles for me with gcc and clang.

Comment: Your *general idea* actually compiles. Have you tried it?

Comment: Initially when I tried it it didn't work, but now it does. I must have done something wrong beforehand. Now it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a temporary vector initialized from an initializer list:

```
 doSomething(std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3 });
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://ideone.com/bsmwdY)

Comment: Thank you so much, I can't believe this hadn't crossed my mind.

Comment: This will initiate copying of passed in vector, because it is passed by value?

Comment: @MartinBerger Was that in question here somehow?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Hi. Your answer is good. I was wondering whether or not this is the case. Is that bad?

Comment: @martin Well, using a reference to a temporary isn't a good idea, unless it's a `const` reference which guarantees lifetime of the temporary is prolonged until the function call is finished. Using a `const` reference would avoid copying, and yes a copy is made in the code I proposed.